# Codename One Location Simulator

Tags: codenameone

Since the Location Simulator is not currently usable (https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3425 & https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3173), is there any way to insert the latitude and longitude that I need to simulate?

I mean that I don't need a map, I already have some coordinates to performs some tests.

Comment: As far as I recall the text fields should work in the simulator. Regardless we have someone coming in to work on this over the summer so this should be fixed in the near future.

Comment: I cannot open at all the Location Simulator because it requires Java FX, that was removed from OpenJDK 11. Have I to download it from https://openjfx.io/? I'm not sure what I have to do. I don't know where the Location Simulator fake location is stored: if it's stored inside Preferences, I can write it in Preferences by myself.

Comment: I suggest using a ZuluFX JVM which includes FX in it as a short term workaround

Comment: I replaced OpenJDK 11 with Zulu-FX-11 (https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?package=jdk-fx), but it still doesn't work. The Location Simulator logs: "This simulation requires a JDK with JavaFX". I completly removed any other Java version (`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove openjdk* oracle-java* && sudo apt install ./zulu11.48.21-ca-fx-jdk11.0.11-linux_amd64.deb`), I added in the Netbeans launcher the parameter `--jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/zulu-fx-11-amd64/` and I check the output of `java -version`, that is: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.48+21-CA. I also fixed the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Comment: Didn't you migrate to maven? Can you check the JDK maven uses? This is usually defined separately in the IDEs maven settings.

Comment: I migrated to Maven. When I launch the Simulator, in the first row of the Netbeans logs it's written: «cd /home/francesco/NetBeansProjects/MyApp; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-fx-11-amd64 /home/francesco/netbeans-12.3/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn -DskipTests=true -Dcodename1.platform=javase -Psimulator verify». The "Location Simulator" still logs: «This simulation requires a JDK with JavaFX». A screenshot of the IDE JDK settings is here: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1997316/123222225-02313f00-d4d0-11eb-83ba-098a1427997e.png I also executed "Run Maven -> Update Codename One".

Comment: I see a problem, I pushed a fix for it. Should be available when maven updates. Notice you should probably switch the lib to use LATEST to get latest updates.

Comment: Solved. I confirm that, after the update, it works like a charm. Thank you very much!